# Bootstrap default debugging script code - is it necessary?

Tags: debugging, twitter-bootstrap-3

In some of the bootstrap example templates they include the following code:

```html
    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Does this mean that those lines should not actually be included in final site builds? I've searched several development sites where people are asking about including bootstrap in their designs and most responses cut and paste from the bootstrap examples including those lines. So just trying to figure out if they should be removed when building an actual site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that those lines should not actually be included in final site builds?

Yes, you should **exclude** those lines. Otherwise, I wouldn't have [added that explanatory HTML comment in the first place](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/c23d6a2766f550c63f7cf64f89296a2bcd52a324).

All [`ie8-responsive-file-warning.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/ab412b2404d12a3c55d1c4b798bd42ef32e80fab/docs/assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js) does is show an error message to developers trying to use `file://` URLs with IE8. It isn't useful in production code.

Likewise, [`ie-emulation-modes-warning.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/docs/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js) just shows an error message to developers trying to ill-advisedly use IE's unreliable emulation modes feature. Again, not useful in production.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank You.

Comment: Ok, just revisiting this to clarify something. When the comment says 'these 2 lines', does it mean the comment line and the 'if lt ie9' line, or does it mean the 2 lines after the comment?

Comment: The lines involving `ie8-responsive-file-warning.js` and `ie-emulation-modes-warning.js`. Which is to say the subsequent 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The lines will make a warning appear for users with IE 8 or older. If that's what you want, leave them in.

Comment: Ok, wish the comment in the code was more clear, though.